# PickerViewにRealmなどのDBから引っ張ってきたDataを選択肢として表示できますか？

Tags: swift

当方初心者です。
予めRealmなどのDBに保存しておいたDataをPickerViewの選択肢として表示することは可能ですか？
人物名を登録画面で入力し、それを別画面で参照して選択したいのですが、ググッてみても参考になるサイトが見つかりません。
お分かりになる方がいらっしゃれば、ご教授下さい。
お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

あなたがどこで困っているのかわからないので、これが回答になるかはわかりませんが、下記はRealmに`Peson`というテーブルで人物名が格納されてるとして、そのデータをビューが表示された時に読み込んでPickerViewに表示するサンプルです。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var token: NotificationToken?
    var people: Results<Person>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let realm = try! Realm()
        people = realm.objects(Person)

        token = realm.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (notification, realm) -> Void in
            self?.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if let people = people {
            return people.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if let people = people {
            return people[row].name
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございました。
試してみます。

Comment: 岸川様
いつもお世話になっております。
上記コードの中盤で、token = realm.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (notification, realm) -> Void in
            self?.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
の中のself?の部分で、Ambiguous reference to member 'pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)' とエラーが立ちます。解決方法はありますか？

Comment: 何か間違ってるのでしょう。これだけだとわからないので、別の質問を作って、そこであなたが書いたコードを載せてください。

Comment: 承知しました。新たに質問とします。